# MVC view testing javascript with Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have MVC view with javascript. What would be the best way to test my view?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JavaScript unit testing framework like [JSSpec](http://jania.pe.kr/aw/moin.cgi/JSSpec)

Additionally, you can use a web app testing tool like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)